# Daily sum by type to show date and '0' even when null (no activity for that type on that date)

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm querying amazon redshift (basically postgresql save for a few features) and am trying to get a daily sum by type for every day (agg daily), but would like to include null as '0' on days where no activity exists for that particular type. I can join another table for dates, but it only seems to work when there is not more than one type.

**using this:**

`select date_dy, type, sum(cost) from data
full join(table_that_includes_all_dates) date_table on date_table.date_dy=data.date_dy`

**gives me this answer:**

```
date_dy     type    sum
8/10/2013   Type 1  466
8/12/2013   Type 1  564
8/14/2013   Type 1  456
8/16/2013   Type 1  878
8/11/2013   Type 2  5461
8/12/2013   Type 2  456
8/13/2013   Type 2  887
8/14/2013   Type 2  52
8/15/2013   Type 2  5456
8/16/2013   Type 2  5488
```

**But what I want it this:**

```
date_dy     type    sum
8/10/2013   Type 1  466
8/11/2013   Type 1  0
8/12/2013   Type 1  564
8/13/2013   Type 1  0
8/14/2013   Type 1  456
8/15/2013   Type 1  0
8/16/2013   Type 1  878
8/11/2013   Type 2  5461
8/12/2013   Type 2  456
8/13/2013   Type 2  887
8/14/2013   Type 2  52
8/15/2013   Type 2  5456
8/16/2013   Type 2  5488
```

Comment: What are the columns on the 'table_that_includes_all_dates' table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select v.date_dy, v.type, sum(coalesce(cost, 0))
  from data
 right join (select date_dy, type from date_table cross join type_table) v
    on v.date_dy = data.date_dy
   and v.type = data.type
 group by v.date_dy, v.type
 order by v.date_dy, v.type
```

**Fiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ebb06/7/0

In the Fiddle notice that 8/12 is missing from the data table, but it correctly has 2 rows, one with Type 1, another with Type 2, both showing zero.

On 8/11 the data table has a row for type 1 but not type 2, but the query correctly shows a 'zero row' for type 2 for that date.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response!  The right join on the date_table (which is just a list of all daily dates) doesn't show the null values on type 1 because type 2 has those dates in them already, so they are excluded (I think this is how it works).  If type 2 did not have those dates, they would be null and I believe I could coalesce them to 0 easily.

Comment: @JeremyTromburg okay I understand your problem a little better; on what table do you hold the list of all possible "type" values? (please provide table name and column names). Also how many different types are there?

Comment: @JeremyTromburg try my edit replacing table and column names with your actual names where necessary

Comment: Still the same result.  The type is also null on 08/11 so it is skipped. If I filter to only one type, the date shows up, but the type column is null Perhaps creating a temp table that has a row for each day and each type on each day and joining would work?

Comment: @JeremyTromburg that would work but to make things easier you can cross join your type table with your date table via an inline view so that you don't actually have to create and maintain the table, for a demo see here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ebb06/7/0 I just edited my answer w/ the query